# How do I get nth element key name from a dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the nth element from a Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172931/how-do-i-get-the-nth-element-from-a-dictionary)

I must get the key name from a dictionary.
[How do I get the nth element from a Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172931/how-do-i-get-the-nth-element-from-a-dictionary) The remedy is not .

```
Dictionary<string, string> ListDegree= new Dictionary<string,int>();
ListDegree.Add( 'ali', 49);
ListDegree.Add( 'veli', 50);
```

I want to get the "ali" with index. The following code get the value "324".What can I do it ?

```
int i=-1;
foreach (var item in ListDegree)
{
    i++;
}
if (i == -1)
    mf.txtLog.AppendText("Error: \"Code = 1\"");
else
    mf.txtLog.AppendText("Error: \""+ListDegree[ListDegree.Keys.ToList()
        [i]].ToString()+"\"");
```

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered, so getting an `nth` element is meaningless. You can use an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet: `ListDegree` is his dictionary as defined in the first code snippet.

Comment: @Jon Skeet sorry. the listdegree is a dictionary object. I edited the question.

Comment: @Oded, I think you answer to this question, please add that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public TKey GetNthKeyOf<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dic, n)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(KeyValuePair kv in dic)
    {
       if (i==n) return kv.Key;
       i++;
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
}
```

****EDIT****

```
public static class DicExt
{
    public static TKey GetNthKeyOf<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dic, n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(KeyValuePair kv in dic)
        {
           if (i==n) return kv.Key;
           i++;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

****EDIT 2****
As @tomfanning said, Dictionary does not provide guarantees on ordering, so my solution is a fake solution, and doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can make it an extension method!

Comment: need to increasing i in for loop. Thank you.

Comment: This is not robust code. Not thread-safe, not guaranteed to be deterministic (`Dictionary<T,U>` does not provide guarantees on ordering), and is not efficient (works by iteration).

Comment: @tomfanning, all the points you have mentioned are from .net dictionary class, and not from my code!!

Comment: That's not relevant. There's simply no such thing as the nth element of a .NET dictionary, so providing an answer that gives the illusion of being a solution seems unwise. Worse so if it's unreliable and inefficient. The answer is, "You can't - use an `OrderedDictionary` instead."

Comment: You are right, I will edit my answer and add this note!

Answer (score 1):

Just as [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) pointed out, why aren't you using an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)?
Here is a sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class ListDegree:OrderedDictionary
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var _listDegree = new ListDegree();
            _listDegree.Add("ali", 324);
            _listDegree.Add("veli", 553);

            int i = -1;
            foreach (var item in _listDegree)
            {
                i++;
            }
            if (i == -1)
                Console.WriteLine("Error: \"Code = 1\"");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Error: \"" + _listDegree[i] + "\"");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mf.txtLog.AppendText("Hata: \"" + anchorPatternClass.GetNthKeyOf(i).ToString() + "\"");
......
    public TKey GetNthKeyOf<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dic, n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(KeyValuePair kv in dic)
        {
           if (i==n) return kv.Key;
           i++;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
```

Comment: Why have you copied an answer someone has given you and posted it yourself?

Comment: Because I cant edit @MSS's post therefore I posted it.

Comment: There was an tiny error in my answer, i didn't increase I.

Answer (score 0):

Although accesing a dictionary by Nth element seems  weird, here is how it might be

```
int N=.....
var val = ListDegree.SkipWhile((kv, inx) => inx != N)
                    .Select(kv => kv.Value)
                    .First();
```